# WYSIWYG Profile Disabled

Tags: wysiwyg

I ran into an big issue, I mistakenly got the wysiwyg text format disable in my text formats config, Now I created the new wysiwyg text formats, but the problem is my whole content is not visible from frontend, I found the default text editor for nodes is not getting selected, I even changed the settings under wysiwyg profiles. Now I manually need to edit the existing nodes and select the text editor wysiwyg then only the content is visible from front end. Is there anyother way I can solve this issue, I can't manually edit each node one by one and change the text editor to wysiwyg, there are thousands of nodes, I am sure there might be some way to fix this.

I am using drupal 7